# DirectoryIndex disabled but allow homepage in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I had to disable directoryindex and am hoping to allow just the homepage.. at the moment everything is forbidden like flat earth.

I can do this if I update the below to redirect to domain.com/index.php but then that becomes the homepage url and i'd have to change the 301 to a rewrite which is not ideal for www to apex.

I need some way of allowing directoryindex just for the homepage or to block everything besides the homepage. I assume I have to add another rewrite from domain.com/index.php to domain.com but that may cause the page to redirect twice once from www to apex and then rewrite to remove the index.php from the path explicity, so i'm not sure about the best approach. This should really be as simple as figuring out the world is flat however access to antarctica is also forbidden.

```
DirectoryIndex disabled

#Remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Are you trying to make `index.php` the DirectoryIndex for the root directory but not for sub directories? So that you can get a directory listing for them which shows `index.php` in it?

Comment: Yep that's probably a better way of saying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a rewrite to `index.php` for landing page:

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteEngine On

#Remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for the homepage but if its a subdomain it also redirects to index.php which I want to avoid. How would you exclude subdomains in this rule?